# Comparison of Hyper-V, Hyper-V Server, VMware ESXi, Xen and Parallels Bare Metal (Community Wiki)

Tags: vmware-esxi, virtualization, hyper-v, xen

Can we use this question to collect information and the pros and cons of each of the above products?

Specifically I am wondering whethere there is any sane reason to use Hyper-V (the role built into Windows Server) over Hyper-V server (the stand-alone product based on the same technology) and what exactly the differences are between ESXi, Xen and Hyper-V and why nobody seems to use Parallels Bare Metal.

Make this a Community Wiki. I want comparisons, not reputation.

Comment: Why the close votes? This is a legitimate question that people will be searching for.

Comment: Because IMHO, as the comments on TomTom's answer below should indicate, this is a very subjective and argumentative question and can't be reasonably answered in this type of forum.

Comment: I found TomTom's answer very objective. And I do think there are objective technical differences between the products to warrant answers.

Comment: I didn't ask which product was "better", I asked for pros and cons.

Comment: @Andrew:  TomTom's answer also addresses licensing which is another topic on SF that can't be reasonably answered either: http://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question.  You asked for my opinion and I gave it to you.

Comment: @Andrew:  Ugh.  Pros and cons are nothing more than opinions and therefore subjective.

Comment: @GregD Right. 64 bit Windows can use more than 4 GB of memory. It's a pro but it's not subjective. Similarly different type-1 hypervisors have different pros and cons. Not everything is subjective. Features can be objectively compared.

Comment: @Andrew:  While what you state is indeed a fact...whether or not it's a pro or con is open to interpretation, which is subjective.  At any rate, I'm not the only one that voted to close this and my opinion isn't the only one that matters.  The now 11 comments alone on TomTom's answer is indicative of exactly why I voted to close this question as subjective and argumentative.

Comment: The 11 comments on TomTom's answer were further questions and clarifications. There was no argument between the participants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Specifically I am wondering whethere
>   there is any sane reason to use
>   Hyper-V

No. Licensing is one (you get free VM licenses with Standard, Enterprise, DataCenter iwindws licenses), but that does not mean yo ucan not still install Hyper-V server adnd keep the papearwork properly. Hardware is currently not a reason - the limits of enterprise edition are pretty high.

Comment: I haven't seen any really compelling reasons NOT to use hyper-v. Granted I don't live in the Enterprise type of environment. My typical hyper-v deployment is rather small. I've got about 20 or so clients running just a handful of VMs each all on midrange HP Proliant servers.

Comment: Ernie, this was about Hyper-V (built into Windows Server) vs Hyper-V Server (stand-alone product).

Comment: TomTom, that's what I thought. But you also get the free VM licences with Standard etc. if you use Hyper-V Server instead of the role.

Comment: Exactly. I had the same question part some months ago asking whether there is a reason not to use the free server part from a technical point of view. With R2 there is not - all features are identical, actually with enterprise (in terms of hardware support). So, I never install a windows core for hyper-v role now, always use the hyper-v server (product).

Comment: @Andrew: No, the hyper-v server does not come with free licenses. BUT - you can still buy the license and assign it (paperwork in lieu). Please point me to other documentation if you have.

Comment: Ha. Right on Andrew.  I see the mixup. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Andrew - I think TomTom is saying that if you use the hyper-v server/r2 products you DON'T get a free license to run a windows OS, which is correct, but that the free server license comes from your Standard/Enterprise/Datacenter License that you purchased.

Comment: One reason I can think to use the Role vs. Server Product is clustering, I don't think you can cluster the stand alone server product.

Comment: @ErnieTheGeek: Which is simply one thing. Wrong. Clustering was added with R2 of Hyper-V server.

Comment: TomTom, I didn't say that Hyper-V Server came with free Windows Server licences.

Comment: To summarise: there is no (sane) reason to use the Hyper-V role over the Hyper-V Server product. However, using the Hyper-V Server product the install and logistics are cleaner.

Comment: In some of my SMB customers I've been using just one server, usually 2008 Standard/R2, as the host and also running the nightly backups through it. I'm running BE 2010 and whatever the specific tape drive for that location happens to be. This isn't my preferred method but it seems to be perfectly functional and not something you could do with just the Hyper-V Server.

Comment: @Ernie That's a good point! I wonder what the recommend method is for backups using Hyper-V Server (or VMware ESXi for that matter).

Comment: The same as for anything else. It is a server core, so you can install technically anything. Software is not allowed, backup agents ARE allowed.

Comment: How does the Server Core figure out whether a given piece of software is "software" (i.e. an application) or a backup program? Does it only allow services?

Comment: I'm fairly certain you can install remote backup agents into the server core. I've loaded some iscsi software into a server core system.

Comment: It does not. Technically it allows software installs. It has limited features (no IIS etc.). Licensing is normally not controlled by allowing installs. FOr example, legal AND needed, I may need to isntall a java based app (to control my raid controller card - yes, happens, adaptec, thanks). Allowed, legal. It is just a limitaiton not to install production software (applications). No coded in control.

Comment: Technically - some software may come with stupid limitations, but then this is not something I would love on a hyper-v only. A good backup / control agent will run on server core without requiring additional installed features / roles.

Comment: So the parent domain of Hyper-V Server is essentially a Windows Server server core installation?

Comment: Yes. One which is stripped of all roles / features not needed, but at the end a normal server core. Best advantage over ESX imho - you still use windows drivers, can use windows tools. Without getting into support hell. This gives you a hell of a hardware base to work with. Granted, some is crappy (i had real problems with some network drivers a year ago), but still it is there.

Comment: Good, I have part of my answer. They can close the question now. :-)